# event count always 11 in Angular Js for ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created the sample of all the Angular Js events . When the first time page is loaded, the value of model textbox is displayed as 11. I would like to know why its value by default is 11.

My HTML looks like below:
        
    
    
        
        Examples on Click events

```
        <input ng-blur="blur=blur+1" />
        Blur Events : {{blur}}<br/>

        <input ng-click="click=click+1" />
        Click Events : {{click}}<br/>

        <input ng-dblclick="dblclick=dblclick+1" />
        Double click Events : {{dblclick}}<br/>

        <input ng-copy="copy=copy+1" />
        Copy Events : {{copy}}<br/>

        <input ng-paste="paste=paste+1" />
        Paste Events : {{paste}}<br/>

        <input ng-cut="cut=cut+1" />
        Cut Events : {{cut}}<br/>

        <input ng-focus="focus=focus+1" />
        Focus Events : {{focus}}<br/>

        <input ng-model="model1=model1+1" />
        Model Events : {{model1}}<br/>

        <input ng-change="change=change+1" />
        Change Events : {{change}}<br/>

        <input ng-keydown="keydown($event)" />
        Keydown Events : {{kdkey}}<br/>

        <input ng-mouseenter="mouseenter=mouseenter+1" />
        Mouseenter Events : {{mouseenter}}<br/>

        <input ng-mouseleave="mouseleave=mouseleave+1" />
        Mouseleave Events : {{mouseleave}}<br/>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My Js code looks like below:

```
    var app5 = angular.module('MyApp5', []);
    app5.controller('eventCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.blur = 0;
        $scope.click = 0;
        $scope.dblclick = 0;
        $scope.copy = 0;
        $scope.paste = 0;
        $scope.cut = 0;
        $scope.model = 0;
        $scope.change = 0;
        $scope.mouseenter = 0;
        $scope.mouseleave = 0;
        $scope.keydown = function(e) {
            $scope.kdkey = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        };
    });
```

Is it because `model` is a `directive` (`ng-model`) and it is counting all other event directive?

I have tried changing `model` to `model1` and other values but still, I always get default value as 11.

Can anyone tell me why?

**EDIT**

The nearest JSFiddle I could come up is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vktdwxz2/).

I could not make it work though.

Comment: This is not work `<input ng-model="model1=model1+1" />`. Because `ng-model` is not **event**.

Comment: could you add plunkr/fiddle by reproducing this issue?

Comment: I advise you to look at the development of the developer tools (console). It shows important information.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Angular sees your variable as a `string` instead of an `integer`

```
console.log(1 + "1") // => 11
console.log("1" + "1") // => 11
console.log(1 + 1) // => 2
```

You should use the `parseInt()` method:

```
console.log(parseInt("1") + 1) // => 2
```

Comment: But then why does it not do for other event counts?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of you have 11 `ng`-directive in your code. And ng-model updated each time when others are updating.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Do you have any link or resource to confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Your example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vktdwxz2/) is terrible.

See fixed [jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/0kuhpr4w/).

```js
angular.module('MyApp5', [])
  .controller('eventCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.blur = 0;
    $scope.click = 0;
    $scope.dblclick = 0;
    $scope.copy = 0;
    $scope.paste = 0;
    $scope.cut = 0;
    $scope.model = 0;
    $scope.change = 0;
    $scope.mouseenter = 0;
    $scope.mouseleave = 0;
    $scope.keydown = function(e) {
      $scope.kdkey = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp5">
  <div ng-controller="eventCtrl">


    <input ng-blur="blur=blur+1" /> Blur Events : {{blur}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-click="click=click+1" /> Click Events : {{click}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-dblclick="dblclick=dblclick+1" /> Double click Events : {{dblclick}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-copy="copy=copy+1" /> Copy Events : {{copy}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-paste="paste=paste+1" /> Paste Events : {{paste}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-cut="cut=cut+1" /> Cut Events : {{cut}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-focus="focus=focus+1" /> Focus Events : {{focus}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-model="model1" /> Model Events : {{model1}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-model="model1"  ng-change="change=change+1" /> Change Events : {{change}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-keydown="keydown($event)" /> Keydown Events : {{kdkey}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-mouseenter="mouseenter=mouseenter+1" /> Mouseenter Events : {{mouseenter}}
    <br/>

    <input ng-mouseleave="mouseleave=mouseleave+1" /> Mouseleave Events : {{mouseleave}}
    <br/>

  </div>
</body>
```